# New GFCI outlet; green light is on but no power

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I installed a new GFCI outlet with an one that was working. I wired it exactly as the older one and it isnt working. The green light is on but no power? I reversed the wires and no light. I replaced it back with the old one and it works.... I purchased a 3 pack of GFCI outlets and tried all 3 of them. None of them work but the old one does... Im stumped and need some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: What part number/brand? Does the green light indicate it is operational & active or reset (test)? Perhaps you have to REALLY push reset.

Comment: Leviton GFTR1-3W 3pk GFCI Outlets 15A-125V I tried many times to press hard on the reset. This is really stumping me... Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, the green indicator light is on and stays on

Comment: Did you tear off the tape that covers the LOAD terminals that says "Do not use the LOAD terminals unless you know what you are doing"?   Most people get into trouble in this area.  Remove any connections, put the tape back, and attach only 2 wires only to LINE until you get this GFCI receptacle to work properly, and always, black on brass, white on silver.  Also tape over or cap any loose wires while you test.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes, I removed the yellow tape and properly inserted the load and line wires. I have installed many regular receptacles and toggle switches including adding outlets. This is my first time installing the GFCI type outlet.

Comment: The current GFCI outlet that is currently installed is working but my wife wants it changed to an updated one with a green indicator light. Again, the old one is working. I shutoff the power and installed the new GFCI exactly as the old one. The green light comes on and stays on but when I insert a night light, it doesn't come on. I checked and rechecked the wiring and used a muti meter and am getting power however anything I plug in doesn't work. I have since reinstalled the "old" GFCI and it is working. I just cant figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Line and load aren't always in the same position. Did you use the taped connection for the load?

Comment: Did you try anything other than the nightlight (ex. is the bulb blown?)

Comment: I am confirming that switching line and load on each side fixed it. The Leviton GFCI outlet was flipped from my old outlet. An easy way to test is to disconnect all black/white wires and put wire nuts on them so they aren't exposed. Then turn the breaker back on. Use a voltage tester to figure out which one has power. That's line. The white wire coming from the same sheath is also line. The other two are load. Then wire them appropriately based on the directions. Like I said, mine were flipped from the past 2 outlets.

Answer (score 30):

The key is that is the Leviton GFCI is lit green from the start it means its wired wrong. Counter-intuitive but true. Had the same problem and some searches finally told me this. I switched both sides top to bottom and bottom to top, and the light flashed red and then went off. Reset it and it went green and THEN I had power. Guess Leviton is wired opposite of others. Remember though, don’t switch left to right...just top to bottom. Black to brass, white to silver.

Just to help clarify: Read where the live and load are on the old unit and which wires go where, then read where live and load are located on the new unit and wire it the same.

Comment: Just for any future viewers of this thread, I can confirm that this answer did indeed work for me.

Comment: this worked for me too!

Comment: Another success. Top to bottom, bottom to top. No light when I turned the breaker back on, but now the outlet will reset and I get the green light.

Comment: Came across this post today and it worked for me, too.  The whole time my wife was telling me, "the light is green so that must mean it's good."  Switched top to bottom, hit reset, everything worked fine.  This was a replacement outlet so I guess Leviton does things their own way.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well, thanks so much! Like others, I replaced an older GFCI with a Leviton and simply copied the wiring from the last one. Turns out I had to swap the two black and two white and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: I found this answer and it has worked for me, as well. I have never had to do this with a GFCI outlet. I would never have thought to reverse the bottom and top wires and then to put them back in the correct position again. But so far, knock on wood, it appears to be working.

Comment: This answer is legit. I just fixed my RV GFCI by swapping the top and bottom wires (not side to side). I don’t know why Leviton does things backwards, but it works now. Thanks! 

Comment: Another happy customer, thanks to Vegas Guy's answer. I had wired my new Leviton GFCI making sure the wires were in the same place as the old GFCI. Nice green light, but no power. Found this answer and all's well!

Comment: Another success with this suggestion. In my case, the previous owner of my home had replaced this outlet in a hurry after the home inspection pointed out an issue and they had wired it up incorrectly, so when I copied the existing wiring I ended up in this situation (green light lit, but no power and TEST button did not work). I never used the outlet, but the indicator had turned red which is why I replaced it. After  swapping the line and load pairs, it tested and powered up as expected.

Comment: This was it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the indicator light is green, then it is telling you that there is power and the device is on. How are you testing it? The only thing I can offer is this site.
http://www.leviton.com/en/products/gftr1-3w
Click on the PDF file "Instruction Sheet" there is a test procedure on the second page.

Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Faulty units, or faulty component, both are unlikely - Try a different electrical device to test, like a lamp

Comment: The modern Leviton GFCIs ship tripped and will not reset unless wired properly. Sounds like something else may be going on

Answer (score -1):

Have you pressed test then reset? Some of the new GFCI'S need to be cycled to turn on the load If the green light is on solid not flashing the instructions say it is properly installed . the new GFCI'S are tough to reset my fingers have a tough time pressing in far enough and now use a tool.
The last Weather resistant Leviton gfci's I installed the terminals were supposed to be torqued to 14 in lbs. All Leviton gfci's are shipped in the tripped condition according to the document that comes with them.  Since solid green= the wiring is good try a test reset cycle.

Comment: Just FYI, the Levitons are indeed shipped tripped but the little light won't turn on without a reset. And, yes, they are annoyingly hard to reset.

Comment: Yes, lots of GFCIs can be hard to reset.  I have large hands and fingers which makes it even harder.  Often I end up using a key or screwdriver to press the button, works great.